# select friends of friends mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
**user**
-id
-first_name

**friends**
-id
-user_id
-friend_id
```

so, table 'users' have

```
'id'  'first_name'
 1      name_1         
 2      name_2         
 3      name_2
```

and 'friends'

```
'id'  'user_id'  'friend_id'
 1      1           2
 2      2           3
 3      3           4
 4      3           5
```

So I need to get 'suggested' friends, friends of friends who is not directly my friends from `users table`.

I tried something like this

```
select distinct users.id
from friends a
join friends b on b.user_id = a.friend_id
join users on users.id = b.friend_id 
where user.id = 3
```

Comment: provide expected result

Comment: expected results for `user.id = 3` should be 1

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much wrong with your query, other than you don't exclude the user for which you're searching for friends from the result set.  In other words, user `3` may have friends whose friends point back to user `3`, so we don't want this suggestion.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    u.id,
    u.first_name
FROM friends a
INNER JOIN friends b
    ON a.friend_id = b.user_id
INNER JOIN users u
    ON u.id = b.friend_id 
WHERE a.user_id = 3 AND
      b.friend_id <> a.user_id
```

Comment: @Strawberry Yes you're right, and shame on me for missing that.

Comment: Oh, come on. No need to be so hard on yourself :-)

Comment: I get the same results. With `user.id = 3` should returns `1` because **user_id 2** have a friend **user_id 1**

Comment: @s78 I think you're getting your column aliases confused.  The query I gave you gives friends of friends for a user whose id is `3`.  Note the condition is `a.user_id = 3` and _not_ `user.id = 3`.

Comment: ohh i see, my mistake. There should be user.id = 3