# Suggest friends of friends in a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to suggest new friends to a user that is specified in a call statement while excluding the users current friends and limiting the result to three suggestions.

These are my two tables:

```
**users**
-id
-username

**friends**
-u_id
-f_id
```

'users' table have:

```
'id' 'username'
 
 1    'arya'         
 2    'jsnow'         
 3    'sansa'
 4    'motherofdragons' 
 5    'theimp'
 6    'jorah'
 7    'sam'
```

'friends' table have:

```
'u_id'  'f_id'
  1       2
  1       3
  2       1
  2       3
  2       4
  2       5
  2       7
  3       1
  3       2
  3       5
  4       2
  4       5
  4       6
  5       2
  5       3
  5       4
  5       6
  6       4
  6       5
  7       2
```

I want the stored procedure to be able to work like call suggest_friends('arya').
The result from this query should be:

```
username

motherofdragons
theimp
sam
```

I've come up with this code so far but this of course doesn't work with any other username than 'arya' in the call statement.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS suggest_friends;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE suggest_friends(username varchar(16))
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.username
FROM friends a inner join friends b on a.f_id = b.u_id
INNER JOIN users u on u.id = b.f_id
WHERE a.u_id = 1
AND b.f_id <> a.u_id
AND u.id != 2 and u.id != 3
LIMIT 3;
END //
DELIMITER ;
CALL suggest_friends ('arya');
```

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019993/select-friends-of-friends-mysql) and tried to copy the answer but still haven't got it to work.

Comment: what mysql version?

Comment: MySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: workbench is a client, not the mysql server.  what does `select version();` show?

Comment: your example shows finding friends of friends and finds three (your limit).  if it only found 2 or less, would you also want to search friends of friends of friends to get up to 3?  deeper than that?

Comment: If it only found 2 or less users I would want the names of that one or two users displayed. For example if a user was friends with everyone I would want an empty display as a the answer.

Comment: select version(); shows 8.0.23

Comment: often friend suggestions pick randomly so that if the user is intentionally ignoring some, they get other options shown other times.  you would do that by adding `ORDER BY RAND()` before the LIMIT 3

Comment: Good to know! Thank you @ysth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I tested it.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS suggest_friends;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE suggest_friends(uname varchar(16))
BEGIN

DECLARE userid INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT id INTO userid FROM users WHERE username = uname;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS excluded;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS excluded (uid INT);
INSERT INTO excluded SELECT userid;
INSERT INTO excluded SELECT f_id FROM friends WHERE u_id = userid;

SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM friends f1
JOIN friends f2 ON f2.u_id = f1.f_id AND f2.f_id NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM excluded)
JOIN users u ON u.id = f2.f_id
WHERE f1.u_id = userid
GROUP BY u.id;

END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL suggest_friends ('arya');
```

Comment: I added LIMIT 3; after GROUP BY and it works great! Thank you @Ergis! :)

Comment: @Robin.G there is no need for limit. Also note, there already is `GROUP BY`. It was my mistake before for not testing it. If it satisfies your requirements, feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: I added the LIMIT 3; because I wanted to have at most three friend suggestions. If I try your code with CALL suggest_friends ('sam'); for example I get 4 friend suggestions. Thank's again!